# Los enlaces deben tener texto

Tags: html, css, html5, google-chrome

Tengo el siguiente problema y he mirado por Google horas y horas, pero no me encuentro con una solución. Cuando utilizo el inspector de *Google AUDITS*, para ver el desempeño, accesibilidad, etc. me aparece lo siguiente:

**Links must have discernible text**

```
<a id="facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"></a>
```

Si creo un enlace sin texto, ¿no es posible? ¿existe alguna solución?

Un saludo!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Cuando utilizo el inspector de Google AUDITS, para ver el performance,
>   accessibility, etc. Me aparece lo siguiente: Links must have
>   discernible text

## Qué es el error

Para una Web Accesible la [W3C](https://www.w3.org) recomienda seguir las recomendaciones de [WCAG](https://www.w3.org/WAI/intro/wcag).

[§ Guideline 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/text-equiv.html)

> Provide text alternatives for any
>   non-text content so that it can be changed into other forms people
>   need, such as large print, braille, speech, symbols or simpler
>   language.

*WCAG* dice que una URL por sí misma no es bastante descriptiva. El autor del sitio **DEBERÍA** proveer una descripción del enlace ya sea através de un `anchor` o a través de un `alt`

Para ver ejemplos, puedes ir a [este enlace](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H30.html)

## Por qué el error

Estás utilizando una herramienta que analiza la accesibilidad del sitio. Toda herramienta que trabaje como validor de especificaciones **DEBE** garantizar que el documento esté de acuerdo a las especificaciones y/o recomendaciones. En caso de no estarlo, la herramienta **DEBE** notificar al autor, puesto que de no hacerlo es lo mismo a indicar que el documento sigue las especificaciones lo cuál no es cierto.

[§ 2.2.1. Conformance classes](http://w3c.github.io/html/infrastructure.html#conformance-requirements)

> Conformance checkers must check that the input document conforms when
>   parsed without a browsing context (meaning that no scripts are run,
>   and that the parser’s scripting flag is disabled), and should also
>   check that the input document conforms when parsed with a browsing
>   context in which scripts execute, and that the scripts never cause
>   non-conforming states to occur other than transiently during script
>   execution itself.

## Conclusión

Debes colocar una descripción a tu enlace si es que quieres que sea accesible por una gran variedad de usuarios, la descripción debe estar presente en cualquier momento incluso sin soporte de JavaScript.

El siguiente código no sigue las recomendaciones de **WCAG**, ya que no establece ningún título descriptivo del enlace.

```
<a id="facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"></a>
```

En cambio el siguiente sí lo hace, ya que puedes ver el texto "facebook" pincharlo e ir al sitio.

```
<a id="facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank">
    facebook
</a>
```

Recuerda que *WCAG* está pensado para usuarios con algún tipo de discapacidad, ya sea visual, auditiva entre otras. Si la naturaleza de tu Web no puede dar soporte a dichos usuarios, entonces puedes ignorar la advertencia, ya que aunque quieras hacer algo por éstos usuarios sencillamente no está en tu disposición poder hacerlo ej: Un videojuego no podría ser accesible por un usuario ciego, por mucho esfuerzo que se invierta.

## Utilizando fontawesome y Bootstrap

Para fontawesome, siempre se recomienda definir las clases de font-awesome en un elemento `inline`, el elemento `inline` no debe tener *anchor*. 
Lo habitual es utilizar `span` para definir un ícono font-awesome.

Respecto a la accesibilidad del enlace deberás utilizar ya sea `aria` o indicar un `title`

En lugar de

```
<a class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
```

Deberás hacer

```
<a class="btn btn-link" aria-label="Ir a Facebook"><span class="fa fa-facebook" /></a>
```

o bien

```
<a class="btn btn-link" title="Ir a Facebook"><span class="fa fa-facebook"/></a>
```

Comment: El problema es que no quiero agregar texto, porque tengo un icono de facebook, utilizando font awesome. el enlace es el siguiente: 

<ul class="social-icons">
 <li>
  <a id="facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" class="fa fa-facebook fa-3x"></a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a id="twitter" href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank"  class="fa fa-twitter fa-3x"></a>
 </li>
</ul>

Comment: @Bob deberás utilizar aria, o algún equivalente nativo de HTML, en el caso de aria sería `aria-label` en el caso de html core  `title`. He actualizado mi respuesta para que veas.

Comment: wuooo que crack! Me pasado días, horas buscando la respuesta. Es más, le pregunte a mi profesor y tampoco daba con la respuesta.

Era agregrar `aria-label="Ir a Facebook"`

Muchas gracias!

Comment: También podrías poner el texto en un `span` y posicionarlo de manera absoluta fuera del enlace para que no se vea pero sí lo detecten los lectores de pantalla. Esa manera siempre me ha parecido la más accesible posible.

Answer (score 0):

> Hay que tener en cuenta que dentro de las etiquetas `<a></a>` hay un texto que aparece **visible para el usuario** sin ello el enlace seria invisible.
>   No obstante, es válido no incluir texto alguno agregando el atributo `name` para hacer referencia al enlace como un marcador dentro de tu página:

```
<a name="arriba"></a>
Volver <a href="#arriba">arriba</a>.
```

Comment: title, aria, anchor, alt, role ... El name sólo debería ser usado para datos que deben ser serializados a través de algún formulario, no como una descripción de un enlace.

Comment: El problema es que no quiero agregar texto, porque tengo un icono de facebook, utilizando **font awesome**, el enlace es el siguiente: 
`<ul class="social-icons">
 <li>
  <a id="facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" class="fa fa-facebook fa-3x"></a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a id="twitter" href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank"  class="fa fa-twitter fa-3x"></a>
 </li>
</ul>`

Answer (score 0):

deberías colocar:

`<a id="facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank">Facebook</a>`

Comment: Entiendo que el autor de la pregunta está intentando crear un enlace sin texto. Y es esa la cuestión que quiere resolver. En tu respuesta se está ofreciendo una solución en la que sí tiene texto el enlace.

Comment: @darioxl Cómo ha comentado Mariano! La solución es _añadir dentro de la etiqueta_ **<a "aria-label="EscribeLoQueQuieras"">** (porque yo no quiero agregar texto en el enlace). Fue resuelto por Eduen Sarceño.